# Ruby on Rails offline programming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am going to be away from the internet for a few weeks and would still like to get a project done.  What steps should I take to make sure I have access to the things I need (ruby and ROR) while I will be disconnected?

Comment: What is this "offline" you speak of?

Comment: You may want to look up what railscamps cache, because they generally involve being offline for the weekend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when offline, the following are hard to get:

- gems
- docs
- rails expert blogs
- stackoverflow ;-)

so,

- gem install as much as you can
- download all the railscasts
- keep one or two rails book around
- and find a place with internet wifi

and most importantly:

- un-plug yourself 2 days **before** the real offline, that's called staging ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you use version control, make sure you can work offline. DVCS do this well, I've heard SVN can work offline if you have a local SVN server.

Running the Rails app on localhost will allow you to access it with your browser locally.

Apart from this it would also be nice to have documentation offline too. Download everything you can think of: Rails, Ruby, Shell, libs etc. Or use books.

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure you have local copies of any documentation you need ([railsapi.com](http://railsapi.com/) lets you download the Rails docs)
- Make sure you have all the gems/plugins you need

Answer (score 1):

This may not affect you, but it's bitten me before.

If you are using a javascript library such as jQuery, and are linking to [Google's Hosted Libraries](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/#jquery) rather than a local one, you may find jQuery stops working when you are offline.

Download and link to a local copy before you go.

Answer (score 1):

Get your app (in its current state) up and running on your laptop.  Then shut off wireless and make sure it still goes.  Don't just guess at what gems and things you'll need - make sure you see it actually run.  Don't forget things like database engines and queuing servers.  Then start guessing about other gems and items you might need.

Make sure that

```
gem server
```

will start up a webserver and let you browse the docs for all your installed gems.

Answer (score 0):

Download every Ruby gem. All of them!

You never know when you'll need to [extract EXIF data](http://exifr.rubyforge.org/), or something.

Comment: I know this is possible, but how do you go about doing it?