# does Ruby On Rails require internet connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does developing in Ruby On Rails require internet connection..or can it be developed without internet connection ..(after installing rails,other gems etc with internet connection)?

Answer (score 6):

Yes and no.

Yes for...

1. Installing and updating gems
2. Deploying your app
3. Communication with external services

No because rails runs on a server which handles all requests on a specified port (default is 3000) on localhost. Routing is handled internally too

Comment: Just as a notice: Even if you have one application updated recently, and want to update the others to the same versions of Gems, you need the internet connection, because Bundler loads at the beginning the index to do the check. So with a fixed set of Gems, you may work without internet connection (but you won't get tips and answers from Stackoverflow :-)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any internet connection. Internet is needed for gems, but not for rails.[Take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728557/ruby-on-rails-offline-programming)

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need. You need internet for installing gems. But not for using Ruby On Rails

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no internet connection needed at all, you are able to develop locally after the installation is done.